# Cannot connect with OLE DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, oledb

OLE DB connection...

Can anyone suggest me on this.

- Authentication with windows security works in 2012-2005

> "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;
>       Initial Catalog=TESTDB;Isolation Level = ReadUncommitted;Data Source=SERVER"

- In 2012 this gives me an error in 2012

> Provider=SQLNCLI11;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=TESTDB;Data Source=SERVER;Language=us_english;User Id=AA;Password=SSS

```
error conn.open
Property access must assign to the property or use its value.
Sql client not registered
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is right there on the last line of the error message:

> Sql client not registered

You need to install the SQL Server Client Library on the machine in question.

You can obtain that package from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239648&clcid=0x409

Also, `Isolation Level = ReadUncommitted` may be problematic if you don't fully understand the implications of `ReadUncommitted` See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Comment: Also, much more material about [using read uncommitted as a magic turbo button, and the pain it can cause](http://www.google.com/search?q=the+problems+with+nolock).